# Как добавить значение в объект в виде пустого списка

Tags: python, dataclass

Создается dataclass с 3 полями:

```
@dataclass()
class Animals:    
    n: int
    id: int
    animal: List[str] = field(default_factory=list)
```

Есть набор словарей:

```
b = [{'n': 1, 'id': 1}, {'n': 4, 'id': 2}, {'n': 1, 'id': 3}]
```

При создании dataclass у нас получается объект с пустым полем animal:

```
b = [Animals(n=1, id=1, animal=[]), Animals(n=4, id=2, animal=[]), Animals(n=1, id=3, animal=[]}]
```

Так же есть другой список словарей:

```
initial = [
{'animal': {'cats': ['шотландец', 'сфинкс', 'манчкин']}, 'id': 1},
{'animal': {'dogs': ['овчарка', 'бульдог'], 'fish': ['окунь'], 'cats': ['сфинкс', 'ориентал']},'id': 2},
{'animal': {'dogs': ['овчарка', 'корги'], 'birds': ['воробей'], 'fish': ['сельдь']}, 'id': 3}
]
```

С помощью следующего кода я получаю список необходимых пород:

```
attr = ('cats', 'dogs', 'birds')

for obj in initial:
    poroda = []
    for type in obj['animal']:
        if type in attr:
            for name in obj['animal'][type]:
                poroda.append(name)
    print(poroda)
```

Как мне в этом коде добавить каждый список в соответствующий объект, чтобы получилось следующее:

```
b = [Animal(n=1, id=1, animal=['шотландец', 'сфинкс', 'манчкин']), Animal(n=4, id=2, animal=['овчарка', 'бульдог', 'сфинкс', 'ориентал']), Animal(n=1, id=3, animal= ['овчарка', 'корги', 'воробей'])]
```

Comment: сделайте словарь - id: [список пород], и при создании объекта отдавайте нужный список из словаря

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Как мне в этом коде добавить каждый список в соответствующий объект,
> чтобы получилось следующее:

```
...

initial = [
    {'animal': {'cats': ['шотландец', 'сфинкс', 'манчкин']}, 'id': 1},
    {'animal': {'dogs': ['овчарка', 'бульдог'], 'fish': ['окунь'], 'cats': ['сфинкс', 'ориентал']},'id': 2},
    {'animal': {'dogs': ['овчарка', 'корги'], 'birds': ['воробей'], 'fish': ['сельдь']}, 'id': 3}
]
b = [{'n': 1, 'id': 1}, {'n': 4, 'id': 2}, {'n': 1, 'id': 3}]
id_by_n = {x['id']: x['n'] for x in b}

attr = ('cats', 'dogs', 'birds')

animals = []
for obj in initial:
    poroda = []
    for type in obj['animal']:
        if type in attr:
            for name in obj['animal'][type]:
                poroda.append(name)
    
    obj_id = obj['id']
    n = id_by_n[obj_id]
    animals.append(Animals(n=n, id=obj_id, animal=poroda))

print(animals)
```

Результат:

```
[Animals(n=1, id=1, animal=['шотландец', 'сфинкс', 'манчкин']), Animals(n=4, id=2, animal=['овчарка', 'бульдог', 'сфинкс', 'ориентал']), Animals(n=1, id=3, animal=['овчарка', 'корги', 'воробей'])]
```

Comment: n надо брать из списка `b` и расширять b породами в соответствии с id

Comment: @splash58, спасибо, не знаю как проглядел :)

Answer (score 0):

Если я все верно понял, то надо что-то вроде этого:

```
b = [{'n': 1, 'id': 1}, {'n': 4, 'id': 2}, {'n': 1, 'id': 3}]
initial = [
{'animal': {'cats': ['шотландец', 'сфинкс', 'манчкин']}, 'id': 1},
{'animal': {'dogs': ['овчарка', 'бульдог'], 'fish': ['окунь'], 'cats': ['сфинкс', 'ориентал']},'id': 2},
{'animal': {'dogs': ['овчарка', 'корги'], 'birds': ['воробей'], 'fish': ['сельдь']}, 'id': 3}
]
attr = ('cats', 'dogs', 'birds')

for d in initial:  # объединяем списки по ключу 'animal' согласно attr и добавляем ключ 'n'
    d['animal'] = sum([v for k,v in d['animal'].items() if k in attr],[])
    d['n'] = next(i['n'] for i in b if i['id']==d['id'])

initial

'''
[{'animal': ['шотландец', 'сфинкс', 'манчкин'], 'id': 1, 'n': 1},
 {'animal': ['овчарка', 'бульдог', 'сфинкс', 'ориентал'], 'id': 2, 'n': 4},
 {'animal': ['овчарка', 'корги', 'воробей'], 'id': 3, 'n': 1}]
'''
```

и список объектов:

```
animals = [Animals(**d) for d in initial]
'''
[Animals(n=1, id=1, animal=['шотландец', 'сфинкс', 'манчкин']),
 Animals(n=4, id=2, animal=['овчарка', 'бульдог', 'сфинкс', 'ориентал']),
 Animals(n=1, id=3, animal=['овчарка', 'корги', 'воробей'])]
```